# Karma disconnects with timeout even with 2 tests

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I want to use Karma test runner with tap test framework for my project and I get stuck for parallel running of tests when there are only 2 tests

I cannot get karma to run when there is more than one test in the test folder. I have searched the issue on the net and see that most people see memory issue because of hundred tests, and mostly solve with changing timeout values. I tried changing all timeout and disconnect values but it didn't help.

I have read all those StackOverflow pages and I don't think this is a memory et all, because the same problem is seen with only 2 test. Somehow people may though its a memory problem up to this day.

And in the test, (this test runs all OK when it's only one test) only first step runs OK where I test the existence of my project -> t.ok(project, 'projectexist')
after that step, I see DISCONNECT error whatever I make timeout value. I also tried to open 2 browsers didn't help (since my test needs partners from browsers.)

```
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 100000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 10,
```

Here is error message I get on the console

```
26 03 2018 09:59:37.240:WARN [Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 7.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 7.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.
Chrome 65.0.3325 (Windows 7.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (10.214 secs / 0 secs)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

And yet another interesting issue I see is, it fails with 2 exact same test, but if I chop one of them I see SUCCESS without running all steps in full test.
let's say I have 2 tests

1 full test
2 1 step only test

Note: Normally full test runs OK when there is only one test, also shows fail correctly if I make the code fail, but this situation above totally strange behavior when there are 2 tests in the folder

karma config file

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    plugins: [
      require('karma-webpack'),
      require('karma-tap'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher')
    ],

    browserDisconnectTimeout: 100000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 100000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 10,
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['tap'],
    files: ['test/**/*.js'],

    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.js': ['webpack']
    },

    webpack: {
      node: {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true
    },

    reporters: ['dots'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Comment: Now I see problem even with one test, I dont think problem is related to any memory issue

Comment: I experienced a similar issue. See my answer here, I hope it helps https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7657